# Why are there outward forces on the ends of a flat plate capacitor?

Tags: field-theory, dielectric

I'm working my way through some formulas for electrical forces on the *dielectric* in a flat plate capacitor. In particular, I have formulas for forces that operate on the interface between the dielectric $(\epsilon_0\epsilon_r)$ and free space $(\epsilon_0)$. I can work the formulas fine, so I don't have a math problem. The rule is that the net force will always point toward the weaker dielectric since $\epsilon_0\epsilon_r > \epsilon_0$.

My problem is in understanding why these two forces even exist because the electric field at the interface is collinear (parallel to) the interface itself. I don't understand how a vector field E can create a force perpendicular to itself across the dielectric interface to the vacuum. See the image below. $E$ is the electric field strength in the image. The flux "pressure" is $\epsilon_0\epsilon_r E^2/2$ and it operates on the end surface (thickness) of the capacitor dielectric to create a force vector.

I have searched a couple of electrostatic textbooks and the net too but without success. No one really talks about the electric field forces that operate on dielectrics or the interfaces between dielectrics. If someone could explain a mental picture of why these forces are there and how they work or point me to a reference link, I would be grateful. Thank you.

PS. If it helps any, I have seen research papers that apply fields to dielectrics as described to get the dielectrics to expand and contract sideways to become electro-mechanical transducers that convert electrical to mechanical energy. But those papers did not explain why the forces arose nor how they operated.

[image]